# In Python 2.x, is there anyway to check if a string can be converted to an integer?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, integer, type-conversion

I want a program to convert user input to an integer and store it in a list only if it can be. If the input is not able to be converted to an integer, the program should just continue and ignore the input.

Comment: Note that there are special cases like `1e+2` etc that can be converted to int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach here is to just try and convert it and ignore the error if the conversion fails.  For example:

```
try:
    your_list.append(int(user_input))
except ValueError:
    pass
```